# Cannot access application after activation on openshift

Tags: web-applications, openshift

I have succefully deployed and activated an application on openshift. 
Now I have no idea how to access it. I thought it would just be the domain name but it still takes me to the "welcome to openshift" page. 
How do I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to signin with your account to openshift then go on the applications page https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications.
Then you should see your applications like on the picture bellow:
[image]

Clicking on one of your applicaitons will show you additional information about it:
[image]

The highlighted in yellow url is suppose to be your app url. Pasting it in your browser should load your site. If still see "welcome openshift.." page on this url, it means that your app has some openshift template as start page and you have to change it to match your expectations.

Comment: I thought something like that was the issue. But I can't find the template. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I do not know what app you have installed. When I deploy python apps I follow the getting started guides from this url https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html. I download the openshift client tools and git, then clone my app with git and rework the openshift templates

Comment: You were right after all. I did some digging and I deleted the templates. Now all I get is a blank page. Thanks a lot!